# Thumbnail image from DNG file is inappropriate using imagemagick or exif tool

Tags: imagemagick, exiftool, dng

I have a DNG image and a cropped monochromatic version of the image. Both are generating the same file as the thumbnail when I run any of the below commands:

```
magick.exe C:\sample1crop.dng -resize 500x375 C:\crop-T.JPG
```

or

```
magick.exe dng:C:\sample1crop.dng -intent relative -sample 500x375> -strip -auto-orient -density 72 C:\crop-T.JPG
```

or

```
magick.exe convert dng:C:\sample1original.dng -thumbnail 500x375 -filter -auto-orient -density 72 C:\orig-T.JPG
```

As I am not allowed to upload the DNG files, thus I uploaded the images in hightail, sharing the link below: https://spaces.hightail.com/space/ThDEDYZVey

The generated thumbnail for both the cases:
[image]

I tried to get the thumbnail with exiftool as well:

```
exiftool -b -PreviewImage C:\86854\SLS\Issues\ART-73712\crop-T.JPG > C:\86854\SLS\Issues\ART-73712\thumbnail.jpg

exiftool -b -ThumbnailImage C:\86854\SLS\Issues\ART-73712\crop-T.JPG > C:\86854\SLS\Issues\ART-73712\thumbnail.jpg
```

but the resulting file seems corrupted. When I extract the exiftool metadata I see:
"ThumbnailTIFF": "(Binary data 42194 bytes, use -b option to extract)"

My requirement here is to get a generic cmd that provides a cropped monochromatic thumbnail similar to the original image.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Why are you telling me you can resize a DNG, if what you actually want to do is extract a preview image? Is extracting a thumbnail preview what you want to do? If so, how is the preview corrupted? In what way? Was there an error? How does it look?

Comment: Hard to be able to help if you do not provide your input DNG. You can always zip the DNG and post to some free hosting service and put the link in your post or a comment.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Using [this exiftool command](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#exiftool--a--b--W-d-f_-t--c.-s--preview:all-dir), I was able to extract [four images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqsFc.jpg) from those files.

You don't mention what OS or shell you're using but if you're using Windows PowerShell, [it is known to corrupt binary data when piping or redirecting](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=8137.msg41663#msg41663).  Use CMD and you should be able to extract the images properly.